# how to find control inside Wizard control in javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, wizard

I have asp.net application having page with asp.net wizard control. this wizard control having the textbox controls. I want to access this textbox value in javascript. 
where as i tried to access this text box control by this :

```
var originalPrice2 = document.getElementById('<%= mytextbox.ClientID %>').value;
or 
var originalPrice2 = document.getElementById('mytextbox').value;

but not getting any value .
```

where as I started firebug I found engine dynamically allocating the id to textbox control as `"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard1_mytextbox"`
and when i tried to get value of text box using this generated id.

```
var originalPrice2 = document.getElementById('<%= ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard1_mytextbox.ClientID %>').value;
```

but getting exception  :

```
The name 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard1_mytextbox' does not exist in the current context
```

Why should be this? my html is exactly same what i explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery:

```
alert( $("input:text[id$='mytextbox']").val());
```

OR

```
var originalPrice2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard1_mytextbox').value;
```

Comment: sure? second option would remain same for all browsers ? I means it should not generate different id dynamically as browser changes , rather it will crashes application.

Comment: what do mean by " different id dynamically as browser changes "? didn't you find text box control?

Comment: tell me who is generating dynamic id here as "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Wizard1_mytextbox" ? if it is not generating browser then it is safe , but if while generating HTML if browser interfering with generated code and if application running in different browser then there may occur of chances to generate different dynamic id for same control . Getting what i want to explain ?

Comment: you don't need to worry about ids. you can use JQuery to get textbox value as explain in first option.here you have to define only id of the textbox control.It will work in any browser.

Comment: wait wait wait...though Id's are generated dynamically by engine ?

Comment: see... yr aim is to get textbox's value client side that u can do from JQuery sample.isn't yr problem solved?? if not post some more code so that i can understand exactly what happened on yr side.